# vim: virtual edit doesn't extend past last line in file

Tags: vim

I have the following in my vimrc `set ve=all`.

When I want to move my cursor past the last line of the file, I cannot. Virtual edit seems to disallow motion past the last line. Is this just a limitation of virtual edit?

I'm trying to make ascii box diagrams.

Comment: Which direction do you mean? To the right, or down?  If you mean to the right, it works fine for me.  If you mean down, you have to create new lines.

Comment: Down. Doesn't it seem wrong that you cannot move past the last newline char?

Comment: It might be easier to use something like this: http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=40

Comment: `virtualedit=all` only lets you move your cursor anywhere within the confines of the buffer.